# DataGridView Column with multiple controls (Radiobuttons, check boxes, list drop downs, etc.)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm interested in creating a DataGridView Column that contains multiple control objects. Specifically, I'd like to build a Column that contains: a text field, a list dropdown, a few checkboxes, and a few radio buttons.

I did some research and came across this page, http://www.codemag.com/article/0707061, which gives a general idea for what I need to do but is it little bit more complex than what I'm looking for. I've not been able to find any examples of adding multiple control objects to a single column.

I'm looking for other resources that I can reference to help me with this task.

This is being done in winforms.

Looks like I'll need to build a custom DataViewGridCell for each control that I want. I can then set the column's .CellTemplate to that Cell. Can a column have multiple CellTemplates?

Comment: Are you doing this in wpf or winforms?

Comment: Edited to include this information, this is in winforms. @MichaelJamesRieger

Comment: Surely you can create a custom column which hosts a composite control in cell while editing. But instead of creating such grid column, you can use a button column and edit values in a window which you open above grid.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is like you suggested. It would be to create a custom `ViewCell` that Inherts from `DataGridViewCell` contains each of the controls you want to add. Then set the template to that column.

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[indexForYourColumn];
DataGridViewCell cell = new YourCustomDataGridViewCell();
column.CellTemplate = cell;
```

Some specific resources to use [CellTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), [CustomControls1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx), [CustomControls2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell)

Comment: When you say create a new UserControl, do you mean to inherit from UserControl? If we do that, then we cannot also Inherit from DataGridViewCell due to not being able to have multiple base classes.

Comment: updated accordingly, differences from WPF to WinForms, had look look at some documentation closer